# Android App Async Failing to load internal data

Tags: android, asynchronous, io

I'm currently learning about IO and Async but am having issues. I'm following a guide, and according to the guide this is supposed to work. I have created an activity with a simple EditText, TextView, and 2 Buttons(save and load). I am trying to have the save button take the text in the EditText and save to internal storage, and the load button take whatever is saved and set the TextView as that. Everything works flawlessly when I put all the code to run in the UI thread, but if I change the code to have the UI thread call the Async class for the loading, nothing seems to happen.

**Packages and imports have been removed to save space.

```
public class InternalData extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText etSharedData;
TextView tvDataResults;
FileOutputStream fos;
String FILENAME = "InternalString";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sharedpreferences);
    setupVariables();
}

private void setupVariables() {
    Button bSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSave);
    Button bLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLoad);
    etSharedData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSharedPrefs);
    tvDataResults = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLoadSharedPrefs);
    bSave.setOnClickListener(this);
    bLoad.setOnClickListener(this);
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bSave:
        String sData = etSharedData.getText().toString();   
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(sData.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        break;
    case R.id.bLoad:    
        String sCollected = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
            byte[] dataArray = new byte[fis.available()];
            while(fis.read(dataArray) != -1){
                sCollected = new String(dataArray);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            try {
                fis.close();
                tvDataResults.setText(sCollected);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

The previous code makes everything work, but the UI lags a bit when trying to load large strings. When I try to have an LoadSomeStuff(Async) class do the loading, it does absolutely nothing when I hit Load on my phone. Within the LoadSomeStuff class it has the doInBackground method open the file and read the data into a string then return that string, and the onPostExecute method set the TextView's text to the returned String. Here's the code:

The onClick method for load button has:

```
    new LoadSomeStuff().execute(FILENAME);
```

LoadSomeStuff Class *Note: This class is declared within the InternalData class.

```
    public class LoadSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sCollected = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
            byte[] dataArray = new byte[fis.available()];
            while(fis.read(dataArray) != -1){
                sCollected = new String(dataArray);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            try {
                fis.close();
                return sCollected;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        tvDataResults.setText(result);
    }
}
```

}

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It actually looks like I had an extra method or two(like onPreExecute) with no code in them and when I deleted them it starting working.